# Set custom validator message using focusout

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to show the same message "Please enter your first name." when the user presses submit as well as if/when the foucusout event happens.

Currently, when the user submits, I get the correct message. When I click into the field, and then tab out (focusout) I get "This field is required". I would like to get into the validation method somehow so the messages are consistent.

Here is the markup I am using:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var messages = {
    'firstNameRequired': "Please enter your first name."
};


$('input[type="text"]').focusout(function(event) {
    $(this).valid();
});

....

function validateForm() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
        'rules': {
            'firstName': {
                'required': true,
                'minlength': 3
            }
        },
        'messages': {
            'firstName': messages.firstNameRequired
        }
        ...
});

// invalid but this is what I'm trying to accomplish:
 $('input[type="text"]').focusout(function(event) {
    $(this).valid({
        // override the default error message...
        'messages': {
            'firstname': messages.firstNameRequired
         }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've removed the `.validate()` method from inside your `validateForm()` function.  The problem is caused because you misunderstood the `.validate()` method.  It's **not** called every time you need validation... it's only called **once** on page load to initialize the plugin on your form.  You're seeing the other messages because the plugin was not initialized properly.

You also don't need the custom external `focusout` handler.  You can use the built-in `onfocusout` callback like this to achieve the same...

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element); //< inside 'validate()' method, this is like 'valid()'
},
```

Do it like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var messages = {
        'firstNameRequired': "Please enter your first name."
    };

    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: messages.firstNameRequired
        },
        onfocusout: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('form is valid');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/JBL48/**

Comment: Thank you!
You are 100% correct. I was misreading the valid() method - and it wasn't getting initialized. I tried using the "onfocusout" property - but it wasn't firing until I tried to submit the form first. This is a huge help. Thank you again!